# SQL Server: flatten PIVOT result

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

A PIVOT function I wrote produces the following result set:

```
Date       | User   | Hour | Result | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 | FIELD6 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
2015-06-23 | Pippo  |   1  |   OK   |  NULL  |  NULL  |   10   |  NULL  |  NULL  | NULL
2015-06-23 | Pippo  |   1  |   OK   |  NULL  |  5     |   NULL |  NULL  |  NULL  | NULL
2015-06-23 | Pippo  |   1  |   OK   |  1     |  NULL  |   NULL |  NULL  |  NULL  | NULL
```

Is there a way, for the rows having the same Date, User, Hour, Result values to aggregate all the FIELD columns into one as following:

```
2015-06-23 | Pippo  |   1  |   OK   |  1     |  5     |   10   |  NULL  |  NULL  | NULL
```

I have tried GROUP BY on (Date,User,Hour,Result) but the PIVOT operator keeps on disaggregating, the same holds for MAX over any of the FIELD# columns.

Any idea?

Comment: Wrap your sql with `select` and do aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `PIVOT` as a subselect and consolidate your results on the main query

```
SELECT      Date, User, Hour, Result,
            SUM(ISNULL(Field1,0) Field1, 
            SUM(ISNULL(Field2,0) Field2, 
            ...
FROM        (   SELECT  ...
                FROM    ...
                PIVOT   ...
            )   Subquery
GROUP BY    Date, User, Hour, Result
```

Comment: Thanks Rubens, but I need to keep the FIELD# columns separate.

Comment: @SimoneF think on your PIVOT result as a table; how could you consolidate your data? In my snippet I kept the `Field#` columns separated.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks. I did more or less the same. What I didn't get before is that I need to aggregate, and thus I need to SUM or MAX the Field#s!

Answer (score 1):

you have to leave only three columns in your subquery.
The `PIVOT`function makes lines for rows with unique ALL columns, not only used in pivot

Comment: I guess I'm stupid, distracted or both. Thanks. Restricting the columns on which i PIVOT and GROUP BY-ing the results with an outer query did the trick.